# Flutter: programming a painting app with scaling (GestureDetector onScaleUpdate, offset calculation after scaling)

Tags: flutter, transformation, gesturedetector

I'm currently trying to program something you might call a 'painting app' using Flutter.
The goal is to use the CustomePainter Widget and Paths, to paint onto an image. I figured out that part, and it works well enough if I don't scale the image. But I also want to make it scalable, so I can get closer to the image to paint in more detail. 
I'm using Paths because I want to make it possible to tap inside the Path and get a response(using 'Path.contains').

The problem, when I use scaling is, that if the scale is smaller, the paint is being delivered to the upper left of there I tap and when the scale is bigger, it's being delivered to the lower right of there I tap. 
I this my problem is just that I miscalculate the offsets. But I couldn't figure out a better formula. 
Also, I have a problem with the movement/transformation after scaling. 
If the Scaled object is either moves slower or faster than the actual movement of the finger. 
I managed to find a solution(by trying to understand the formula) that moves the object at the right speed, but the initial position is either to the lower right or upper left, depending on the scale.

I think all I need is the right formula for the Offset that accounts for scaling.

Also, I noticed, that the Gesture Detector does not detect anything out of the initial area, so if I scale the image down, taps on the image get detected, but gestures outside the image get ignored. 
Is there a way to detect all gestures on the screen?

I'm fairly new to Flutter and programming in general, so I might ask really stupid questions, but I, unfortunately, couldn't find any answers to these problems.

In the code below, I included both alternative codes I used for obtaining the offset. Both have their perks, and I would love to get the initial positioning from the one code alternative and the correct movement calculation from the other...

About the code: you press the 'gesture' icon in the app bar to switch between moving the content and drawing on the content, use pinch to zoom in and out and the 'trash' icon to undo the drawing

//edit: explain the code, add network image and change one icon 
//edit1: change the title

```
import 'dart:ui';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class GesturePaint extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _GesturePaintState createState() => _GesturePaintState();
}

class _GesturePaintState extends State<GesturePaint> {
  List<Offset> points = List();

  Offset _startLastOffset = Offset.zero;
  Offset _lastOffset = Offset.zero;
  Offset _currentOffset = Offset.zero;
  double _lastScale = 1.0;
  double _currentScale = 1.0;
  bool _drawable = true;

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('painting app'),
        actions: <Widget>[
          IconButton(
            icon: Icon(Icons.gesture),
            onPressed: (){
              setState(() {
                _drawable = _drawable ? false : true;
              });
              print(_drawable);
            },
          ),
          IconButton(
            icon: Icon(Icons.delete),
            onPressed: (){
              setState(() {
                points.clear();
              });
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
      body: _buildBody(context),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildBody(BuildContext context){
    return GestureDetector(
      child: Stack(
        fit: StackFit.expand,
        children: <Widget>[
          _transformMatrix4Image(),
          //_transformScaleAndTranslate(),
          _transformMatrix4(),
        ],
      ),
      onScaleStart: _onScaleStart,
      onScaleUpdate: _onScaleUpdate,

    );
  }

  void _onScaleStart(ScaleStartDetails details) {
    print('ScaleStartDetails: $details');

    if(_drawable){
      setState(() {
        points.add((details.localFocalPoint/_currentScale).translate(-_currentOffset.dx,-_currentOffset.dy));
      });
    } else{
      _lastScale = _currentScale;
      _lastOffset = _currentOffset;
      _startLastOffset = details.focalPoint;
    }

  }



  void _onScaleUpdate(ScaleUpdateDetails details) {
    print('ScaleUpdateDetails: $details - Scale: ${details.scale}');

    if (details.scale != 1){
      double currentScale = _lastScale * details.scale;

      setState(() {
        _currentScale = currentScale;
      });

      print('_scale: $_currentScale - _lastScale: $_lastScale');

    } else if(details.scale == 1.0 ) {
      // Calculate offset depending on current Image scaling.
      if(_drawable){
        //draw instead
        setState(() {
          // this does generally not work, i also tried to use FocalPoint, which doesn't work either,
          // and i tried to use (details.localFocalPoint).tranlate, which also didn't work well
          //the following is the closest i come to the initial movement, but the offset is off depending on the scale
          points.add((details.localFocalPoint/_lastScale).translate(-_currentOffset.dx,-_currentOffset.dy));
        });
      } else{
          Offset offsetAdjustedForScale = (_startLastOffset -_lastOffset )/ _lastScale;
          //initial offset correct, but moves at different speeds than finger movement with following code:
          //Offset currentOffset = details.focalPoint - offsetAdjustedForScale*_lastScale;
          //initial offset wrong, but moves with correct speed
          Offset currentOffset = details.focalPoint/_lastScale - offsetAdjustedForScale*_lastScale;

          setState(() {
            _currentOffset = currentOffset;
          });
      }
    }

  }


  Transform _transformMatrix4(){
    Matrix4 _mat = Matrix4.identity()
      ..scale(_currentScale,_currentScale)
      ..translate(_currentOffset.dx,_currentOffset.dy);
    return Transform(
        transform: _mat,
        alignment: FractionalOffset.center,
        child:  PathExample(pointsList: points),
    );
  }

  Transform _transformMatrix4Image(){
    Matrix4 _mat = Matrix4.identity()
      ..scale(_currentScale,_currentScale)
      ..translate(_currentOffset.dx,_currentOffset.dy);
    return Transform(
      transform: _mat,
      alignment: FractionalOffset.center,
      child: Image(
        image: NetworkImage('https://png2.kisspng.com/sh/dde5d7f3f60acef81f7e019f4f65cafb/L0KzQYm3VcA1N6Vxj5H0aYP2gLBuTfJtfZYygtNELX3yhbB7gflvNZNxjddraYLnPcjwjvcuPZJqe9ZqZkS5QIi6VcAvPmIAUKoEOEm0RYO8VMcyQWk9S6sAMT7zfri=/kisspng-blue-jay-mountain-bluebird-wing-5aecdaf4607350.6198898915254719883951.png'),
        fit: BoxFit.cover,
      ),
    );
  }


}







class PathExample extends StatelessWidget {
  PathExample({this.pointsList});
  List<Offset> pointsList;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return CustomPaint(
      painter: PathPainter(pointsList: pointsList),
    );
  }
}

class PathPainter extends CustomPainter {
  PathPainter({this.pointsList});
  List<Offset> pointsList;

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    Paint paint = Paint()
      ..color = Colors.red
      ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke
      ..strokeWidth = 8;

    for (int i = 0; i < pointsList.length - 1; i++) {

      Path path = Path();
      if(pointsList[i] != null) path.moveTo(pointsList[i].dx, pointsList[i].dy);

      for(int j = i; j < pointsList.length - 1;   j++ ){
        if (pointsList[j] != null ) {
          path.lineTo(pointsList[j].dx, pointsList[j].dy);
        } if(pointsList[j] == null){
        }

        i = j;
      }
      canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
    }

  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(CustomPainter oldDelegate) => true;
}
```

Comment: https://github.com/pskink/matrix_gesture_detector/blob/master/lib/matrix_gesture_detector.dart

Comment: I need a little time to understand the code, but looks like that's what I needed.

Comment: i noticed that you dont support rotation, so you could remove "rotation part" from my code: [line 165](https://github.com/pskink/matrix_gesture_detector/blob/master/lib/matrix_gesture_detector.dart#L165)

Comment: okay, so scaling and translating works perfectly using this code, but I can't figure out how to get the offset(position of the tap) out of the matrix4. edit: yeah, I just used the code and set the 'shouldRotate' value to 'false'.

Comment: *"but I can't figure out how to get the offset(position of the tap) out of the matrix4"* - sorry i have no idea what you mean by that

Comment: okay so why I've done is: take the class MatrixGestureDetector and use it instead of the Gesture Detector. For 'onMatrixUpdate' I used a function that uses the Matrix4 matrix, to either transform everything or draw on the canvas. But so far, I only managed to make it transform properly and move the lines with the correct speed when drawing, but the positions are off, as I can't find a way to get the position of my finger on the screen. But I guess I should  rather try and use the code and modify it accordingly.. will be the next thing I try.

Comment: check https://github.com/pskink/matrix_gesture_detector/tree/master/example/lib - there are samples that use `Transform` widget and `CustomPaint`

Comment: yeah, I ended up using the demo for Custom Painter as a reference and added the variable 'localFocalPoint' to onMatrixUpdates by: RenderBox renderBox = context.findRenderObject();
    Offset localFocalPoint = renderBox.globalToLocal(details.focalPoint);
with the localFocalPoint and the transformation matrices, I was able to make it all work :) thanks!

Comment: sure, your welcome, btw now `ScaleUpdateDetails` has `localFocalPoint` property, so no need for `RenderBox`...

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example app with both zooming and drawing modes you can toggle between by pressing the hand button. However, there's one problem when you wrap GestureDetector in InteractiveViewer (see issue: [How to zoom a GestureDetector with onPanUpdate call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67005002/how-to-zoom-a-gesturedetector-with-onpanupdate-call))

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(new MaterialApp(
  home: new IssueExamplePage(),
  debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
));

class IssueExamplePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _IssueExamplePageState createState() => _IssueExamplePageState();
}

class _IssueExamplePageState extends State<IssueExamplePage> {
  bool drawingBlocked = false;
  List<Offset> points = [];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Container(
          color: Colors.grey,
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
          child: Container(
            color: Colors.white,
            child: InteractiveViewer(
              child: AbsorbPointer(
                absorbing: drawingBlocked,
                child: GestureDetector(
                  behavior: HitTestBehavior.translucent,
                  onPanUpdate: (details) {
                    RenderBox renderBox = context.findRenderObject();
                    Offset cursorLocation = renderBox.globalToLocal(details.localPosition);

                    setState(() {
                      points = List.of(points)..add(cursorLocation);
                    });
                  },
                  onPanEnd: (details) {
                    setState(() {
                      points = List.of(points)..add(null);
                    });
                  },
                  child: CustomPaint(
                    painter: MyPainter(points),
                    size: Size.infinite
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
        children: [
          FloatingActionButton(
            child: Icon(drawingBlocked? CupertinoIcons.hand_raised_fill : CupertinoIcons.hand_raised),
            onPressed: () {
              setState(() {
                drawingBlocked = !drawingBlocked;
              });
            }
          ),
          SizedBox(
            height: 10
          ),
          FloatingActionButton(
            child: Icon(Icons.clear),
            onPressed: () {
              setState(() {
                points = [];
              });
            }
          ), 
          SizedBox(
            height: 20
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyPainter extends CustomPainter {
  MyPainter(this.points);
  List<Offset> points;
  Paint paintBrush = Paint()
    ..color = Colors.blue
    ..strokeWidth = 5
    ..strokeJoin = StrokeJoin.round
    ..strokeCap = StrokeCap.round;

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    for (int i = 0; i < points.length - 1; i++) {
      if (points[i] != null && points[i + 1] != null) {
        canvas.drawLine(points[i], points[i + 1], paintBrush);
      }
    }
  }
  
  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(MyPainter oldDelegate) {
    return points != oldDelegate.points;
  }
}
```